# ¿Como editar una url con JS?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

En los JS que estoy desarrollando debo de ingresar y/o usar una `url dinámica` por si algún caso el nombre del proyecto cambia...

por tal motivo intente usar lo siguiente:

```
alert(window.location.pathname);
```

el cual me muestra lo siguiente `/proyecto/index.php/usuario/`

¿como podria modificar esto `(window.location.pathname)` de tal forma que no me muestre el nombre del controlador que en este caso es `usuario` si no unicamente esto? **/proyecto/index.php/**

Agradeceria inmensamente si me pueden colaborar con esto.

Comment: Usando una expresión regular que empiece recorriendo desde el final de la url y elimina de la String los caracteres que se encuentre hasta el segundo "/" (este no incluído).

Comment: Hola @Eduardorq gracias por el interés, pero no lo he entendido.

Comment: Puedes usar la `API` [history](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/DOM/Manipulando_el_historial_del_navegador) de `HTML5`. Consulta el método `replaceState`.

Answer (score 1):

Si pretendes hacerlo con Javascript, intenta con [`history.pushState`](https://alyssa.is/pushstate-jquery/), con ello puedes cambiar las direcciones.

De acuerdo con [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API), como debes hacerlo es:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
    var stateObj = { estado: "ok" };
    history.pushState(stateObj, "página 2", "dirección.html");
</script>
```

Esto causará que el navegador muestre la dirección `http://midominio/dirección.html` pero sin redireccionar ni comprobar si `dirección.html` existe.

Answer (score 1):

```js
path=window.location.pathname;
alert(path.substr(0,5+path.indexOf(".php")));
```